# Can you attach sounds to a VTK simulation?

Tags: python, audio, vtk

I have following scenario:

I want to have a vector field simulation which shows the current of a fluid, lets say water. This current produces a certain noise, which can change when a solid object is submerged into the current.

Is there a way to somehow attach this noise/sound to the visuals of VTK?
I am not really experienced with VTK, so any point in the right direction is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say the vector field simulation of a current produces a certain noise. Is this data produced by VTK, what format is it? Is it an audio stream or some other form of representation of noise?

Comment: So I don't have an actual simulation yet. I am currently just looking for technologies where this is possible. The data of the noise is not produced by VTK, but calculated separately. The format of the data is variable, depending on what library/framework is recommended for the actual audio output.

Comment: It is more of a general question, like is it possible to have a vtk simulation with some sound attached

Comment: That would be a separate dataset (eg a vtkTable), but yes you can store sound in .vtk file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty general question on an esoteric topic. A good first step in these cases is to do a scientific journal review to see what researchers have attempted before, what tools they used and what success they had. After a quick search I found a few relevant journals that cover generating sound from simulations/data.

[Sounding liquids: Automatic sound synthesis from fluid simulation](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1805964.1805965)

[Visual to Sound: Generating Natural Sound for Videos in the Wild](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/html/Zhou_Visual_to_Sound_CVPR_2018_paper.html)

[Auditory Display and the VTK Sonification Toolkit](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.219.3861&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

[Listen to your data: Model-based sonification for data analysis](https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/42206399/HermannRitter1999-LTY-with-cover-page-v2.pdf?Expires=1659086981&Signature=cfB0bdtm7jtdCZER-DAwnVpiZt99pvR5yRHRzkwzG1k6eIrbaWvLoG3kzS1IZg7%7E5ce0K75nmXpRZ4AbGY9RBVwsRLzV%7E6fWIckGO%7ExYSGv--crtpjN0mj540lCuSr3e9ySNSPsxpqeQ%7EpO-SIG5cG1Cy3uBLXZBPF30PoyLWy6pFnKyoJjeJMHP15cRDXyK3mJuy8XbPHPcftMMkwp%7E4UXdoJDTFzh1BdN%7ECFtN3LiDBajkCSsuRrhitQgedCLHbNJZS8kXN0cDOIX5imfmY89n9ECatCaA4eYqI-Nxrq57juBzWGfPChzOc8M-U1vdq0RfRmVADWsGUyhwbZiR%7Eg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA)

After reviewing these, you'll have a better idea of what's already been attempted and what's possible.